# Want logo to overlap navigation bar and have navigation text vertical-align: middle with logo

Tags: html

Problem:

I have added a logo to the middle of my navigation bar. This is causing my navigation bar to not line up correctly and I am unable to center the logo with the navigation bar (I want it to overlap but still be centered) and vertically align text with the middle of the logo.

You can find an image of my website here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DBB455104AF221A9!15298&authkey=!AHytmSrx1n-yf78&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png

The navigation bar is grey and the navigation links are outlined in red.

Here is my HTML code

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#music" id="nav-music">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pictures" id="nav-pictures">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home" id="nav-home"><img id="home-logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#videos" id="nav-videos">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#social" id="nav-social">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
#nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;    
}

#nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;   
}

#nav li{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block; 
}

#nav a{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000; 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have searched this website and was unable to find a question that was similar to this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add CSS for image: (give some height & width)

```
#home-logo {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer RealDeepak. That definitely fixed the formatting issue I had but not completely what I was going for. I attached a sketch of my intended design and also of what your suggested code changed. How can I overlap the logo on the navigation bar and vertically align the navigation text to the middle of the logo on the navigation bar? Thanks again!

Here are the images:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DBB455104AF221A9!15308&authkey=!ACdGr46k_rIzyiQ&ithint=folder%2c